# GroupBy a bindingList

Tags: c#, linq, bindinglist

I've created a `message` class for my users:

```
public class Message
{
    [DisplayName("Message")]
    public string shortContent { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Line")]
    public int line { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("File Name")]
    public string file { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Level")]
    public MessageLevel level { get; set; }
    ...
}

public enum MessageLevel
{
    Information,
    Warning,
    Error
}
```

To display this to my loved users, I bind it to a custom binding list (in order to allow them to sort the messages).

I would love to be able to group the messages by some properties (`level`, `shortContent` essentially) but I can't find any easy way to do it with `Linq`.

I've tried to use GroupBy with no luck. What I would love is to transform this:

```
Message                     Line    File Name           Level   Date                Read    Full message
The device is not ready.    46      OpenFileControl.cs  Error   24/09/2015 3:01     True    
The device is not ready.    46      OpenFileControl.cs  Error   24/09/2015 3:02     True    
Some Random message.        -1      Unkown              Error
```

to:

```
Message                     Count
The device is not ready.    2
Some Random message.        1
```

Comment: What is not working for you when using `GroupBy` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GroupBy should work. Bear in mind you are *not* modifying your binding list, so anything bound to that won't notice you are grouping at all.

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.Message)
    .Select(x => new { Message = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
```

Comment: I've got : cannot convert from `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Common.Message>'`
Do you have a magic trick?

Comment: Well, that is because to get the count you need to project it into something, you can't assign it back to a collection of `Common.Message`. You can create your own type `MessageCounts` that has `Message` and `Count` properties and use that in the `Select` clause. 

Do you need to display this somewhere? What do you want to do with the grouped data?